# How to decide which plugin to use in maven?

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

I was going through the maven documentation. I saw maven works using plugins, for each phase there is one or more plugin and for each plugin there is one or more goals. there are plugin for compile, install, deploy, clean etc. I saw in my project they used maven-clean-plugin. Then how maven clean install command is working if we did not put the maven-install-plugin? Question might be bit silly but i am new the this world and appreciate your help.

Comment: https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.6.3/maven-core/default-bindings.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That would follow up with some default configuration of each plugin inherited with Maven's BOM. Executing

```
mvn dependency:resolve-plugins
```

shall help you identify these versions of the plugins inherited.

So primarily to ensure you work with a specific(or updated) version of the plugin with the desired configuration of your project, you can explicitly define them in the `pom.xml`, otherwise, just let be.

Comment: Yeah, true. @JFabianMeier Even I don't think that way. But I wanted to refer to the parent most pom(in Maven) in some way.

Comment: You mean the super POM, not the BOM, right?

Comment: yeah @JFabianMeier

Comment: Yes I saw even if I commented the compiler plugin, the build was successful. So, my understanding is, all the default plugins comes from the Super POM. right? I executed the command you provided i saw maven-compiler-plugin and maven-install-plugin. Therefore, it comes from super POM. Thanks for the explanations.

Answer (score 0):

The Maven lifecycle has standard bindings for plugins to the different phases.

If you run `mvn clean install` you run the plugins that a attached to the phases by default.