# How the maven compiler plugin come into effective POM even if it is not there in Super POM

Tags: maven, pom.xml

Last few days I was working on maven topics. I realized all the default plugins comes from super pom as per this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65507580/how-to-decide-which-plugin-to-use-in-maven/65508177#65508177). I executed the command `mvn dependency:resolve-plugins` after removing the compiler plugin i could see all the plugins there. My question is if i am not mentioning in my pom those compiler plugin then from where those plugin coming to my effective pom. I could not see compiler plugin the  [Super pom](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.6.3/maven-model-builder/super-pom.html).

Your inputs are valuable.

Comment: Okay. So it comes from the packaging type. Therefore, if we do not need to change the version of the compiler and all we do not need to explicitly mention those plugins. am i right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default plugin bindings do not come from the super POM, but from the default lifecycles:

https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#built-in-lifecycle-bindings